# How to send one-to-one upstream messaging using not not using FCM without hosting a server?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

> Sending messages from one device directly to another device it not supported through Firebase Cloud Messaging.
>     -- Frank van Pufflenen - ***JUNE 23 2016***

That was quite some time ago, and there aren't any updates in the docs. However:

- Has there been any changes?
- Is Firebase the only option? Are there any other app servers (Like Firebase and the shut-down **Parse**)?
- I don't want to find/buy a server just for this.  But is the Firebase Server SDK suitable for this?
- Can this be implemented using GCM?

Comment: "That was quite some time ago" -- that was five months ago.

Comment: @CommonsWare anything could happen in 5 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been lots of changes.

But:

1. Sending a message from one device to another still requires the use of a server key, which means you will need a trusted server.
2. Recommending services is off-topic here on Stack Overflow.
3. The Firebase Server SDK is for use on a trusted server.
4. No, sending device to device messages was only possible with Google Cloud Messaging by using a trusted server.

Also see my answer here for the architecture of sending downstream messages: [How to send one to one message using Firebase Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993724).

Comment: Thanks. But WILL there be a feature in the future?