# How to send a push notification to a specific user using my app?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am thinking about developing a personal application for me and my SO. What it does? It sends a simple notification:

> Thinking of you, hope you are doing allright!

I want it to be send through data. The receiver should only get a notification if connected to data, for example like messaging in Whatsapp works.

The question is: What is the simplest way to make sure that both our phones are connected / authenticated? Maybe through signing into Google+? I fear that implementing a Google+ sign in would be way too complex / unnecessary for my Use Case.

Example: User A has this app installed. User B installs it too and A gets a notification saying that User B has this app installed. Now A can choose to request a connection. User B confirms and from then on, both can quickly send each other a simple notification.

Comment: Store GCM/FCM unique id on server using REST API and select that user and send to him/her.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. Little Question: I read that GCM is still supported since a lot of apps are still using it. What are the advantages of Firebase Cloud messaging compared to GCM? Do they benefit complex applications or also simple things?

Comment: They are mostly the same. in short: gcm is old and fcm is new -> use fcm

Comment: Alright. Will do!

Comment: @Suroko, check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990140/how-to-send-one-to-one-message-using-firebase-messaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is the simple and easy way to send Push Notifications using 
***FireBase*** :

If you want  premium provided guide follow

Udacity`s [Advanced Android Development](https://www.udacity.com/course/advanced-android-app-development--ud855)
if you want a simple guilde [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuiuVDb2bug)

Personally i recommend Udacity`s  Guide, also completing the whole course,

the link i attached is a free version of that tutorial.
 You could check out the whole Android Development Guide provided by Google.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks! I have been working through Google's development guide in the past and found it to be quite hefty. I thinks it's great for people who already have some experience with OOP and programming