# Trying to send notification from user to user FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a notification to a user but I am unsure if i am using correct approach as from running this code there is no new notifications in firebases console. I am able to pass the token of the destination and title and body however i am not sure if the post request is correct. Any advice would be great thanks.

```
public class ClientNotifications extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    String token;
    String titles;
    String body;
    public ClientNotifications(String token,String title,String body)
    {
        this.token = token;
        this.titles=title;
        this.body=body;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {

        JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
        // client registration key is sent as token in the message to FCM server
        jsonObj.addProperty("token", token);

        JsonObject notification = new JsonObject();
        notification.addProperty("body", body);
        notification.addProperty("title", titles);
        jsonObj.add("notification", notification);

        JsonObject message = new JsonObject();
        message.add("message", jsonObj);

        final MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");

        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        try {
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/yourfirebaseproject/messages:send")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "key")
                    .post(RequestBody.create(mediaType, message.toString())).build();

            Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("HI",e.toString());
        }

        return message.toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Checkout this article https://blog.usejournal.com/send-device-to-device-push-notifications-without-server-side-code-238611c143

Comment: This is the right url => https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work:

```
.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "key")
```

You would need to pass the actual server key here, not just the string "key".

It's worth pointing out that you're not supposed to provide this key to your client application, as that's a security hole.  The end user should never be able to get a hold of server keys that give privileged access to APIs.  Your client app should instead invoke a secure backend to do the work of sending the message.

Also I will point out that you're not actually checking for errors in the request.  The result of the call to FCM should tell you in more detail what you did wrong (but passing the string "key" is definitely not right).

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i originally just used key as a place holder instead of putting my exact key on here

Comment: *firebaser here* As Doug said putting your FCM server key in a client-side application is a huge security risk, as it allows a malicious user of your app to send any of their messages to any of your users. In fact, I was just helping a developer whose app had gotten a significant number of users change their FCM configuration keys this week because they had done this in early releases of their app, and who were seeing precisely this abuse by a malicious user.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, @Frank van Puffelen, so I should be storing this key server side?

Comment: Yes. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990140/how-to-send-one-to-one-message-using-firebase-messaging/37993724#37993724

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
    jsonObj.addProperty("to", token);
    jsonObj.addProperty("content-available", true);
    jsonObj.addProperty("priority", "high");

    JsonObject notification = new JsonObject();
    notification.addProperty("body", body);
    notification.addProperty("title", titles);
    jsonObj.add("notification", notification);

    final MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "key=your_key")
                .post(RequestBody.create(mediaType, jsonObj.toString())).build();

        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("HI",e.toString());
    }
```

I fixed what I can see. Good luck