# Android Studio Push Notification on Button Click

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app where I can post an announcement with Firebase Realtime Database by button click.

I'm looking for a way to send a push notification to all devices when I click on the Button in my app.

Comment: There is no way to send a message to other devices through FCM (known as a downstream message) directly from a device, as that would be a pretty big security risk. Instead: you must always send messages to devices from a trusted environment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990140/how-to-send-one-to-one-message-using-firebase-messaging/37993724#37993724

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't want to send a specific message to other devices. I want just a notification "New Announcement" on every device when I click the Button. Or does this not make a difference?

Comment: That's a specific message, as the "New Announcement" is part of the message you want to send.