# Unity Firebase Cloud Messaging SendAsync Missing

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/topic-messaging
Stated in the document that you're able to send a message.
But in my version, 7.0.2, there is no SendAsync method.
Does anyone know how I can send a message from a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SendAsync` method you found in the documentation is only available in the (.NET) Admin SDK:

```
await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
```

This `SendAsync` does not exist in the Android/iOS SDK or the Unity wrappers around that. There is no way to send messages directly **from** a device, as this would be an insecure operation - allowing all users to send whatever message you want to all other users.

Instead, you'll need to send the messages from a trusted environment, such as the Firebase console, your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. See [How to send one to one message using Firebase Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990140/how-to-send-one-to-one-message-using-firebase-messaging/37993724#37993724)

Comment: Thanks for explaining I understand better now!