# How to send simple "push notification" from one device to other device?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application that I made with Flutter. I am trying to write a method for users to add each other as friends in my application, but before I do this, I want to send push notifications from one device to the other. Actually, I think if I start, I can solve the rest with my own algorithm.

Ways I've tried:

- installed node.js
- from project terminal: firebase login
- firebase init
- functions file created and exists in my project
- i have index.ts file
- **I get unique token for each device when app opened.**

I want to put a simple notification sending code in the index.ts file, but I couldn't. And this notification should work from one device to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple solution to send device to device notification.
First create json formatted parameters like below

```
    var params = {
  "to": "device token",
  "notification": {
  "title": "Notification Title",
  "body": "Notification Message",
  "sound": "default",
  },
  "data": {
    "customId": "01",
    "badge": 0,
    "alert": "Alert"
  }
};
```

Then `var url =  'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';` call as api.
Get response like below code

```
    var response = await http.post(url,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "key= Web server Key over here",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },body: json.encode(params)
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
  print("fcm.google: "+map.toString());
}
else {
  Map<String, dynamic> error = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print("fcm.google: "+error.toString());
}
```

Comment: How to fill that "Web server Key over here" part?

Comment: I try to make that at mobile application

Comment: you get key from firebase console of you project. And yes this is for mobile app. I've been use this in my mobile applications too.

Comment: I want to ask one last question, which file should I put these codes in?

Comment: Hit this with code whenever you need to send notification. You can even simply try it with button click to test it first.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
<HTML>
^

I get error like this. Do you know this?

Comment: i think i made a mistake at : `Then var url =  'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'; call as api. Get response like below code` part. There is no `fcm.googleapis.com`

Comment: I get authorization error: Status Code 401. Something's wrong but i dont know which parts

Comment: I FOUND THE SOLUTION !!! I made a mistake, i get Web API Key instead of Server Key ! Thank you

Comment: *firebaser here* Calls to the FCM REST API require that you specify the FCM *server** key in your code. As its name implies, this key should only be used in server-side code, or in an otherwise trusted environment. The reason for this is that anyone who has the FCM server key can send whatever message they want to all of your users. By including this key in your Android app, a malicious user can find it and you're putting your users at risk. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993724 for a better solution.