# Send notification over device using FCM and Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

currently I am trying to send a notification to multiple device. I already read the documentation on how to [send notification to device group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group) , they mentioned that I need to use `registration_ids: [...]` instead of `to: token`. And I also read somewhere that they mentioned about `notification_key` which is it will enabled to send the notification to the other device. So, I'm stuck on finding the key. But then, after few days browsing, I found out that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) stated that the `notification_key` already deprecated. So, I would like to ask if any of you guys know how to send notification to multiple device without using console.

This I my code segment to send push the notification:

```
try {
  await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
    // Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification'),

    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'key=$serverKey',
      'project_id':'....',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(
      <String, dynamic>{
        'notification': <String, dynamic>{
          'body': 'this is a body2',
          'title': 'this is a title'
        },
        'priority': 'high',
        'data': <String, dynamic>{
          'click_action':
          'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
          'id': '1',
          'status': 'done'
        },
        'registration_ids': ['fbN9aYoORhihksrTo7j5D2:APA91b......', 'fArqpgKrTJ0fL8SUKddy2F:APA91bFWf1cnVMS8.......'],
        // 'to': _token,
      },
    ),
  );
} catch (e) {
  print("error push notification");
}
```

It work fine if I used `to` instead of `registration_ids`, but the things is as I understand is to is used if I want to send notification only for one device.

I already stuck with this issue for three days and still not found any solution. Most of them are using console instead. Your help will really made my day. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution and its work!

```
 var serverKey =
    'AAAAUb...';
QuerySnapshot ref =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get();


try {
  ref.docs.forEach((snapshot) async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=$serverKey',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        <String, dynamic>{
          'notification': <String, dynamic>{
            'body': 'this is a body',
            'title': 'this is a title'
          },
          'priority': 'high',
          'data': <String, dynamic>{
            'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            'id': '1',
            'status': 'done'
          },
          'to': snapshot.data() ['tokenID'],
        },
      ),
    );
  });
} catch (e) {
  print("error push notification");
}
```

Comment: *firebaser here* Calls to the FCM REST API require that you specify the FCM *server** key in your code. As its name implies, this key should only be used in server-side code, or in an otherwise trusted environment. The reason for this is that anyone who has the FCM server key can send whatever message they want to all of your users. By including this key in your app itself, a malicious user can find it and you're putting your users at risk. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993724 for a better solution.