# Is there any alternative to notification notify device but without sending native notification?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Example: I have mobileDevice1 / mobileDevice2 / laptop

Goal: I need to notify mobileDevice1 with some message by sending it from mobileDevice2 and laptop. The message need to passively appears (listens) on mobileDevice1 without any interaction like pressing update button. But the thing here it must be not a regular push notification because this message must not appear in the mobileDevice1 notifications list. It can appear in some view for example regular recyclerView but not in native device notifications list

Is there a way to do that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to send a [data-only message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages), which is always [delivered to the `onMessageReceived` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) in your application code and never displayed by the system.

Comment: do I understand right that I can send this message from any Android / iOS / web to my Android mobile app as a message and catch it with the listener?

Comment: Sending messages *to* a device has to be done from a trusted environment. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993724 But your question seemed to be about how to send a message without ever showing a notification, which is done through a data-only message.