# Firebase notification OnClick

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, push-notification

I have made a Java app in which users can chat I what to add a feature through which when a user clicks on Button View a notification will be send to all users using [FCM or Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

Comment: what prevents you from doing it?

Comment: use subscribe to any topics  topics for all users

Comment: *firebaser here* Calls to the FCM REST API to *send* messages require that you specify the FCM *server** key in your code. As its name implies, this key should only be used in server-side code, or in an otherwise trusted environment. So there is no way to directly send a message from one device to another. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993724 for a better solution.