# Sending a notification to my Website from a button press on android (React Native)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I am creating a function in my application, using React Native, which will send a message on my web page.
Basically, after the button is pressed in the application, a message will appear on the web saying that it is working.
I searched a lot on the subject, and Firebase Send Notifications function is always indicated. How can I implement this function?

Comment: Assuming you want to use Firebase Cloud Messages for this, there is no way to send a message to a device directly from another device. There will always need to be a server, or otherwise trusted environment, involved. For more on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993724