# Send topic message to users on firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I do not find an example of how to send topic messages using Firebase Messaging on Flutter. On this tutorial [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/topic-messaging), it shows how to handle topics but not how to send the message.

So far, I am able to subscribe to a topic using `FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("topic");`

I can see that there is a function `FirebaseMessaging.instance.sendMessage` but don't understand how to use it. I have searched online but cannot find a proper example of how to send messages to users subscribed to a particular topic.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics. And if you're wondering how to do this from your Flutter code, that isn't possible to do securely. Sending messages must always happen from a trusted environment. For more on that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993724 and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture.

Comment: How about sending just a notification, but this is what I need basically. Is it possible to do so directly using Firebase Flutter SDK?

Answer (score 2):

Your secured backend should handle the sending. On the same page that you linked to, there is a link at the bottom with a good description on how to send to topics.

Link to that documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics

Comment: How about sending just a notification, but this is what I need basically. Is it possible to do so directly using Firebase Flutter SDK?

Comment: No, it is not possible.