# push notification using firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to sent notification the code is :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

Future<void> sendTripReminder() async {


  final DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
  final DateTime parsedTripDate = DateTime.parse("2023-09-25");

  // Calculate the time difference between the current date and trip date
  var timeDiff = parsedTripDate.difference(currentDate).inDays;


  // If the trip date is within a specific threshold (e.g., 2 days), send the notification
  if (timeDiff == 2) {

    // Retrieve the FCM token
    final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    String? token = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();

    final String serverKey = "AAAAF2P0ikc:APA91bFHuOyG9_o3HHH5bCrGwst4ctupvt2Kba1O2Yf1ZmXttfXKVsV-RiUFN90GSZKdgHr0u8jBcJVTZO5fdzu3NnzZereWeehtsiE_m0ZJCSDM9L45LI1WlTMMoQy5531fzMBkVyC_";

    final Map<String, dynamic> message = {
      'notification': {
        'title': 'Trip Reminder',
        'body': 'رحلتك قادمة في 2023/09/25. امضي وقتا طيبا!',
      },
      'token': token,
    };

    final Uri uri = Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    final http.Response response = await http.post(
      uri,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=$serverKey',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(message),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Notification sent successfully');
    } else {
      print('Failed to send notification');
      print('FCM Response Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('FCM Response Body: ${response.body}');
    }
  }
}
```

I get in terminal :

> I/flutter (16358): Failed to send notification
> I/flutter (16358): FCM Response Status Code: 400
> I/flutter (16358): FCM Response Body: to

how I fixed ?

Comment: *firebaser here* Calls to the FCM REST API require that you specify the FCM *server** key in your code. As its name implies, this key should only be used in server-side code, or in an otherwise trusted environment. The reason for this is that anyone who has the FCM server key can send whatever message they want to all of your users. By including this key in your Flutter app, a malicious user can find it and you're putting your users at risk. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993724 for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code calls `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`, which is the legacy API that is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref). Based on that documentation, this API expects a `to` parameter - not a `token` parameter as you are passing.

If you're trying to use the newer, versioned API - you can find its reference documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send). That also contains the URL you need to call for this newer API: .