sending notification one to one in flutter using api googleapis (postman)
I am trying to send notification one to one (chat message). So if X send message to Y, X will hit the api googleapis :
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send

{
   "message":{
      "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
      "notification":{
        "body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
        "title":"FCM Message"
      }
   }
}

I get it from the documentation firebase : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1.
So for sending message to Y, I need ID Device token of Y right, is there anyone know how to retrieve it ? as I know this code below only retrieve my ID Device token:
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
String? token = await messaging.getToken();


firebaser here Calls to the FCM REST API require that you specify the FCM server* key or administrative credentials in your code. As its name implies, these values should only be used in server-side code, or in an otherwise trusted environment. The reason for this is that anyone who has these credentials can send whatever message they want to all of your users. By including this key in your Android app, a malicious user can find it and you're putting your users at risk. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37993724 for a better solution.
